# How make Intellij Idea debug a Play 2.1 app's source code files, instead of project definition only

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.1

When I create a new Play 2.1 project, Intellij Idea insists on debugging the project configuration files only. That is, lines in ./project/Build.scala, and no other files.

How do I tell Idea to debug stuff in ./app/ instead?

I've generated Idea project files like so: `[project-name] $ idea with-sources=yes` (in Play's console).

<sub>(I cannot remember this ever happening before with Play 2.0 or earlier versions of 2.1)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were 2 causes for this issue: one "interesting" and one stupid.

*The interesting cause:*

Play 2.1 and SBT seems to fork tests (and thus run them in a separate process). Therefore breakpoints in my unit test code were never hit.

One way to "fix" this, is to add this config settinig:

```
Keys.fork in Test := false
```

*The stupid cause:*

I had not yet compiled any "real" source code files in the new project. So therefore Idea never activated breakpoints on those lines.  But the *project configuration* Build.scala file was compiled when I launched Play's SBT console I think, so Idea activated breakpoints in Build.scala directly. — So there was never a problem really: I just had to hit `run` in the Play console and then the breakpoints came alive (after Play had compiled my sources).

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Intellij, with remote debug on port 9999
1. ~apatzer> play debug
2. Then start my Remote configuration in Intellij
3. [playproject] $ run
==> Successful at hitting breakpoints and debugging.

Because of forking, I was unable to hit breakpoints in any of my tests.  For example:
[playproject] $ test-only com.mydomain.pkg.MyTest
==> FAIL different process.  Breakpoints not hit in IDE.

Here's what worked:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object MyBuild extends Build {
...
lazy val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
  Keys.fork in testOnly := false,
  libraryDependencies ++= deps,
  ...
```